# f is convex if and only if $f(x):=\left \langle Mx,x\right \rangle \ge 0$

Tags: matrices, analysis, convex-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I have to show for $M \in \mathbb{R}^{(N \times n)\times (N \times n)}$ symmetric Matrix and $f:\mathbb{R}^{N\times n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x):= \langle Mx,x\rangle$ that:

f is convex if and only if $f(x) \ge 0.$

where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{N\times n}$.

I don't know how to proof that. Perhaps someone has a hint.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i was trying to do it by contradiction (first direction) with using the usual definition of convexity: $f(\lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$ i also tryed to use the fact that the second derivative of f is bigger than zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is convex $\iff$ the Hessian of $f$ is positive semi-definite. The Hessian of $f$ is the martix $2M.$

Hence: $f$ is convex $ \iff M$ is positive semi-definite $ \iff \left \langle Mx,x\right \rangle \ge 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: thank you, but i don't understand the last step. why do i have 
M is positive semi-definite $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\langle Mx,x \rangle \geq 0$

Comment: what is the definition of positive semidefinite?

Comment: a matrix is semidefinite if $x^{T}Ax \geq 0$. so i have to check that $\langle Mx,x \rangle = x^{T}Mx$ ?

Comment: if i have n=0 than it is clear but i don't understand how to interpret the multiplication of $Mx$ when $n \geq 1$.

Comment: $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is just notation for the inner product.

Answer (score 1):

That does not seem right to me. Let $ \mathbb{R}^{{n \cdot (n + 1)}/{2}}$ be the space of the $n\times n$ symmetric matrices . Not every convex function $ f: \mathbb{R}^{{n \cdot (n + 1)}/{2}}\to \mathbb{R} $ is of the form $ f (X) = \langle M \cdot X, X \rangle $. The function 
$$
\varphi(X)=\|X\|_{\infty}= \max\left\{|X_{ij}|: X=(X_{ij})_{n\times n}\in \mathbb{R}^{{n \cdot (n + 1)}/{2}}\right\}
$$
is convex because that every norm in a finite dimensional space is a convex fuction. It is a consequence of triangular inequality: for all $t\in[0,1]$ we have 
$$
\|t\cdot X+(1-t)Y\|_\infty\leq \|t\cdot X\|_{\infty}+\|(1-t)\cdot Y\|_\infty\leq t\cdot\|X\|_{\infty}+(1-t)\cdot \|Y\|_\infty
$$
It is easy to see that there is no constant matrix $M\in \mathbb{R}^{({n \cdot (n + 1)}/{2})\times ({n \cdot (n + 1)}/{2}) }$ such that
$$
\langle M\cdot X, X\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^{{n \cdot (n + 1)}/{2}}}=\|X\|_\infty=\max_{ij}|X_{ij}|
$$

Comment: The formulation of my question ist not really precise. The function is defined to be $f(x):=\langle Mx,x \rangle$. But thanks for answering.